# How to connect flutter to Bluestacks emulator?

Tags: dart, flutter, android-emulator

I'm setting up an Android device for flutter development and need to have a lightweight emulator. How do I connect bluestacks to flutter? Since the android studio is too slow for my machine and I only have an iPhone.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, You can connect Flutter to Bluestacks.

You have to enable `adb` on Bluestacks' configurations, by following:

```
gear icon > Advanced configs > (marks as true: enable ADB connection)
```

after that, you must to restart your bluestacks, then open a terminal and go to your Android SDK folder:

```
%localappdata%/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
```

then type the follow commands:

```
adb connect localhost:5555
```

So, by now if you type `flutter devices` you will get the emulator device name on the list, then you can run your apps on it

Answer (score 3):

In this case what I would like to suggest you is to download GenyMotion. 
Is a very lightweight emulator and it has its own plugin for Android Studio.

I was on a similar situation with an AMD processor and this was a really helpful way for me to test my apps.

Here is the URL for download: http://cloud.geny.io/

Comment: @Brayna Is GenyMotion is free to install? Or Do we need to pay to for it?

Comment: It's not a free software

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps

1. Install the latest version(4.180.10.1006) of bluestack
2. Open the bluestack
3. Enable the adb by setting>preferences>tick "Enable Android Debug Bridge"
4. Open the cmd
5. Create a flutter project by typing "flutter create [projectName]"
6. Access to your project folder by typing "cd projectName"
7. Run flutter app by typing "flutter run"

#### How to enable adb over bluestack

[Step1 - Click the setting(gear)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcm23.png) 
[Step2- Click the preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNqrj.png) 
[Step3 - Scroll Down to Enable Android Debug Bridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpYLA.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Hello, I hope it's not too late for you - but:*

You can use *sublime text* as editor and for running your app.
You can use *command prompt (`cmd`)* on windows and as an emulator, you can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com).
It will fit for you if you need a light editor along with a good emulator that does not take too much RAM space.

I have tested it, and it was running perfectly. 
However, the problem were flutter packages for sublime text(coding helper).
I couldn't find any packages for sublime text, only dart. You can update the question for further information.

*I hope you understand this and it will help you.*

Comment: I don't have another free vote for today to flag the low quality of the description, so I decided to fix it myself and provide an edit suggestion. Please check if this is what you meant.